# Having trouble calling two variables from method into main C++

Tags: c++, methods

I am having trouble with a very simple program. I need to call in a method (getNumber) outside of main that takes two numbers from the user and then store those numbers. Those two numbers are then used in a calculation method (math) which is also called into main. I am getting an uninitialized local variable for my two numbers I am calling in from getNumber. I would like the user to enter two numbers have them added together and display the result but by calling in methods.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getNumber(int x, int y)
{
    // here is where the user is prompted to input two numbers
    cout << "Please enter two values" << endl;
    cin >> x >> y;
    return x, y;
}

int math(int x , int y)                             // here is where the    calculations are done
{
    int result;
    result = x + y;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int result;

    x = getNumber(x, y);     // trying to call in the input method here
    result=math(x,y);       // calling in claculation method
    cout << result;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pass by reference, pal. And your return statement is nonsensical. Instead of guessing, read your C++ book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void getNumber(int &x, int &y)
{    
     cout << "Please enter two values" << endl;

     cin >> x >> y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much you have been such a great help